# How to allow user to reorder list when presented with one?

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, for-loop, data-science

I want to create a list of unique values from a column of a DataFrame and then allow the user to sort the list arbitrarily based on their preference of the items in the list. For example:

```
fruit_info = pd.read_csv('Fruit Information.csv')
fruit_list = (fruit_info['Fruit Name'].unique().tolist())
print(fruit_list)

['Apple','Banana','Cherry','Orange','Watermelon']

sorted_fruit_list = [favorite, 2nd favorite, 3rd favorite, ..., least favorite]
```

I have tried creating a dictionary with the fruits as keys and passing ranked integers as values and then sorting the dictionary by values and converting to a list, but it seems clunky. Is there a better way to get user input and then pass the new order to the list? Thank you!

Comment: What is the question: (1) How to design the user interface for reordering (what should the user enter and what should be the result) or (2) how to implement it then?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use a loop to prompt the user to enter their ranking for each fruit in the list, and then sort the list based on the user input?

```
import pandas as pd
fruit_info = pd.read_csv('Fruit Information.csv')
fruit_list = fruit_info['Fruit Name'].unique().tolist()

# Prompt the user to enter their rankings for each fruit
rankings = {}
for fruit in fruit_list:
    rank = input(f"Enter your ranking for {fruit}: ")
    rankings[fruit] = int(rank)

# Sort the fruit list based on the user's rankings
sorted_fruit_list = sorted(fruit_list, key=lambda x: rankings[x])

print(sorted_fruit_list)
```

Hope that my answer can provide you with some insights :)